# Qt and Android - Get path from image in gallery

Tags: android, c++, qt, gallery

I have done a code to get an image from `Android gallery`. I am using `QtAndroid` to write a equivalent java code in Qt.

I have already opened the gallery, selected the image and received the path, but it returns the `MediaColumn` of the file and I need the absolute path.

How can I get the absolute path of the file using `QAndroid` to write a Java equivalent code in Qt?

Here is the code I have done:

imagepickerandroid.h

```
#ifndef IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
#define IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

#include <QDebug>

class imagePickerAndroid : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    imagePickerAndroid();

    void buscaImagem();

    virtual void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject & data);

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoSignal(QString);
};

#endif // IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
```

imagepickerandroid.cpp

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>());
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Trabalha com os dados";

    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        QString imagemCaminho = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;").callObjectMethod("getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;").toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);

        qDebug() << imagemCaminho;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Here is the code to get the `full image path` from `android gallery` using `java` equivalent code written with `Qt`:

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/content/Intent", "ACTION_PICK", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    QAndroidJniObject EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$Images$Media", "EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI", "Landroid/net/Uri;");

    QAndroidJniObject intent=QAndroidJniObject("android/content/Intent", "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/net/Uri;)V", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>(), EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.object<jobject>());

    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");
        QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$MediaColumns", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;");
        QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
        jobjectArray projecao = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
        jobject projacaoDadosAndroid = env->NewStringUTF(dadosAndroid.toString().toStdString().c_str());
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(projecao, 0, projacaoDadosAndroid);
        QAndroidJniObject contentResolver = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
        QAndroidJniObject cursor = contentResolver.callObjectMethod("query", "(Landroid/net/Uri;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;", uri.object<jobject>(), projecao, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        jint columnIndex = cursor.callMethod<jint>("getColumnIndex", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I", dadosAndroid.object<jstring>());
        cursor.callMethod<jboolean>("moveToFirst", "()Z");
        QAndroidJniObject resultado = cursor.callObjectMethod("getString", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", columnIndex);
        QString imagemCaminho = "file://" + resultado.toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested it on many phones and usually it's ok. But today I've discovered that on an Xperia Z1 with Android 5 it always returns an empty string. Have you noticed this problem?

Comment: Na I haven't. I have only tested in other models.

Comment: It seems it's an Android 5.1.1 bug, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567217/android-5-1-1-lollipop-return-null-file-path-if-image-chosen-from-gallery
It would be great to fix this code using the suggestions provided in that question.

Comment: As I can see you need to create a method to return a `uri`, the method called ` handleImageUri` in the link you posted above and use this uri as a parameter in the `handleActivityResult`

Comment: handleActivityResult doesn't get called for me (first time I try to call java from C++) although the gallery app is opened.

Comment: Oy vey! It just was because I created imagePickerAndroid stack based and not on the heap.