# Getting "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference" on lollipop and above

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bitmap, onactivityresult

I have an option to set an image either by capturing it or by choosing it from the gallery.

The method is working fine on versions below lollipop, but the app is crashing giving `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/18 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference` on lollipop and above versions.

Here's how I am launching the chooser:

```
protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Take picture
                    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                    break;
                case 1: // Choose picture
                    Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    choosePhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(choosePhotoIntent, PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST || requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // display an error
                    return;
                }
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap convertedImage = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 300);
                hPic.setImageBitmap(ExifUtils.rotateBitmap(picturePath, convertedImage));
                hPicTag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        // error on the line below
        int width = image.getWidth();
        // 
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }

    public static class ExifUtils {
        /**
         * @see ://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html
         */
        public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(String src, Bitmap bitmap) {
            try {
                int orientation = getExifOrientation(src);

                if (orientation == 1) {
                    return bitmap;
                }

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                switch (orientation) {
                    case 2:
                        matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        matrix.setRotate(180);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        matrix.setRotate(180);
                        matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        matrix.setRotate(90);
                        matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        matrix.setRotate(90);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        matrix.setRotate(-90);
                        matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        matrix.setRotate(-90);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return bitmap;
                }

                try {
                    Bitmap oriented = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    return oriented;
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return bitmap;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

    }

    private static int getExifOrientation(String src) throws IOException {
        int orientation = 1;

        try {
            /**
             * if your are targeting only api level >= 5 ExifInterface exif =
             * new ExifInterface(src); orientation =
             * exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5) {
                Class<?> exifClass = Class
                        .forName("android.media.ExifInterface");
                Constructor<?> exifConstructor = exifClass
                        .getConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
                Object exifInstance = exifConstructor
                        .newInstance(new Object[] { src });
                Method getAttributeInt = exifClass.getMethod("getAttributeInt",
                        new Class[] { String.class, int.class });
                Field tagOrientationField = exifClass
                        .getField("TAG_ORIENTATION");
                String tagOrientation = (String) tagOrientationField.get(null);
                orientation = (Integer) getAttributeInt.invoke(exifInstance,
                        new Object[] { tagOrientation, 1 });
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Fragment.InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return orientation;
    }
```

As I'm just a beginner, I'm totally confused about why am I getting this error.

Please let me know.

Sorry for bad formatting of the question. I'm still learning to post good questions.

Comment: How are you launching the camera? Could you share your code of this part?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez please see the edited question

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567217/android-5-1-1-lollipop-return-null-file-path-if-image-chosen-from-gallery but if you want to make you life somewhat easier then just use an image loading library like Glide or Picasso.

Comment: @JohnWowUs I'm using Picasso. Life is much easier now ;p